# Get “Objects in arrays are not well supported” with new schema in Kibana Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, kibana

I have a multi log type in my system. I want to aggregate this Log and index it into Elasticsearch. my final schema is below.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": 2,
    "history": [
        {
            "login": {
                "time": "123",
                "text": "aaa"
            },
            "logout": {
                "time": "124",
                "text": "bbb"
            }
        },
        {
            "login": {
                "time": "125",
                "text": "ccc"
            },
            "logout": {
                "time": "126",
                "text": "ddd"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I index this schema to Elsaticsearch search I get below warning in Kibana(Discover tab).

> Objects in arrays are not well supported

[image]
but I can filter on all fields!

- why this warning show?
- Elasticsearch is not supported object in array?
- What do I do?
- is another way to index this type of schema?

[discuss.elastic.co link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/get-objects-in-arrays-are-not-well-supported-with-new-schema-in-kibana/206905)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **nested** type instead of object

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you need to be able to do this then you should use the nested datatype instead of the object datatype.

[More about](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html)

You can create a dynamic mapping

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "objects": {
            "match_mapping_type": "object",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can create your own schema

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "history": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "login": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "text": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "time": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "logout": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "text": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "time": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Soheyl Was it helpful? did you manage to work with **Nested** datatype?

Comment: :| I get this error  "object mapping [history] can't be changed from nested to non-neste"

Comment: Did you delete your index first?

Comment: Yes. Also I create a new index!